# Can files be easier corrupted by using download accelerator?

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, browser, download, download-manager

I am not very technically informed, so my question might not make sense at all.

I want to know if downloading files online using download manager/accelerator like IDM or eagleget tend to be more prone to corrupted files downloaded than conventional, probably due to multiple parts of a file gathered up from various sources and stitched back together.

Are there reported cases of file corruption resulting from use of download managers?

Another question is, would it have negative impact on SSD such as causing more writes to the drive?

Thank you a ton.

Comment: If they were then applications like IDM wouldn't be used.  There is zero impact on the storage device.

Answer (score 1):

I used IDM for download 26gb mp4 file. IDM downloaded it very fast speed at 36mbps but file somewhere corrupt. When I download it on Microsoft Edge with 14 to 16 mbps downloading speed. File was ok. The same with 1.5gb to 7gb files I checked all, problem was same with fast download cause files corrupt.(files download from Google drive)

Answer (score 0):

The main task of download managers is to monitor the network connection (to recover from failures, to re-request network packets if damaged). The only thing they can do with the file system is just to help it - file managers can try to continue downloading the file (without downloading it in its entirety).

Answer (score 0):

By "download accelerator" you probably mean a download manager that uses
multiple threads for reading the file from a website.

This could be used when the website in question has some limit on the
speed of each connection, so by using multiple connection it is possible
to better use your bandwidth. In all other cases, there is no advantage
to using multiple threads.

I have myself used such download managers for years with no problem.
I would suggest using one that supports "Restart", because it would
be built to recover from crashes or other disconnection issues.
It would carefully record what it is doing on the disk, so it can
continue from nearly where it was stopped.

Using multiple threads would do exactly the same number of disk accesses
to download the file as would do a one-thread (not advanced) process.
So there is no negative impact on the disk.